# Problem using Filters and Sprites in a StageGL context

Tags: createjs

First of all, sory my English.

I am working with some sprites using WebGL on CreateJS library. I need apply a custom color filter over the jpg used to create the spritsheet.

Here is my code:

```
let bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(rscTexture);
bmp.filters = [new createjs.AlphaFilter()];
bmp.cache(0, 0, rscTexture.width, rscTexture.height, {1, useGL:"stage"});

let frames = this.generateFrames();
this.sprite = new createjs.Sprite( new createjs.SpriteSheet({
  framerate:  24,
  "images": [bmp.cacheCanvas],
  "frames":  frames,
  "animations": {
    "run": [0, frames.length - 1],
  }
}));
```

The problem is that this trow next error:

> ERROR Cannot use 'stage' for cache because the object's parent stage
>   is not set, please addChild to the correct stage.

How can I add the element to the stage first, if I still do not create it?

Comment: sory, line 3 is: bmp.cache(0, 0, rscTexture.width, rscTexture.height, 1, {useGL:"stage"});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a StageGL instance that already exists, you can pass it in directly instead. The "stage" shortcut attempts to figure it out; however, sometimes you need to be specific and directly passing the reference is the only solution.

`bmp.cache(0, 0, rscTexture.width, rscTexture.height, 1, { useGL: myStage });`

The specific and full documentation can be found here:
https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/BitmapCache.html#method_define